# show average and sum of table cells

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i have table for quiz results, in the table there a cell for grade.

Example (cell grade is in a while loop and the numbers appears after checking the other cells with if):

```
    <table border="1">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th> id </th>
          <th> question </th>
          <th> answer </th>
          <th> correct answer </th>
          <th> grade </th>


        </tr>

        <tr>

          <td> 1 </td>
          <td> question how bla bla bla</td>
          <td> bla bla answer</td>
          <td> correct answer</td>
          <td> 5 (this cell has the grade of each question)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

          <td> 2 </td>
          <td> question2 how bla bla bla</td>
          <td> bla bla answer2</td>
          <td> correct answer2</td>
          <td> 8 (this cell has the grade of each question)</td>
        </tr>
```

etc

```
// in this cell i want to show me the average from td grade

<td colspan="4" align="center">average</td>
  <td><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="Avg" /></td>      


      </tbody>
    </table>
```

thanks a lot!!

Comment: the question is not clear. what is your html structure and what javascript code have you tried to get cell data?

Comment: i have in a table cell some number and i want to appear in an other two cells the average and count of these numbers. i'm new and i dont know how to do this with javascript.. for example the name of <td> is grade show me in a cell the count of numbers of cell grade

Comment: Please edit the question and post the actual html, not just a description.

Comment: You said this numbers are not from database, then why have you shown the mysql query here. Better to remove it and put only relevant info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this tut http://www.amitpatil.me/table-manipulation-with-jquery/ What You are probably looking for is mentioned in the 5th point on above page ie "5) Find all the values from td of particular column "

```
$(".grid tr").each(function(i){
   colValues[i] = $('tr:nth-child('+(i+1)+')>td:nth-child(1)').html();
});
```

Comment: ok thanks a lot. i want to get the values and with some function to show the average and count.. i'm little confused because i'm new

Comment: Once you get all the values combine all them with + (make sure you wrap variables in "parseInt"), i think i dont have to explain you how to calculate additions and average is it ?

Comment: i'm new in javascript - jqeury and i need help to everything.. ;) i'm searching to google how to do this

Comment: this maybe help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812548/sum-table-row-text-fields-with-running-overall-total-in-text-field

Comment: can you help me to change the code of this page: http://jsfiddle.net/kauhikoa/mXNU3/1/ to my case? all the numbers is in td: <td>grade</td> and i want to show the average in input box like this page

Comment: Edit your question and put sample table data with values.

Comment: in this page there's the correct javascript code of the example which send you before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812548/sum-table-row-text-fields-with-running-overall-total-in-text-field

Comment: thanx a lot!! you help me a lot! the only difference is tha i want to show the results in this <td colspan="4" align="center">average</td>
  <td><input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="avg" name="avg" /></td> and <td colspan="4" align="center">total</td>
  <td><input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="total" name="total" /></td> and no in an alert box

Comment: Dude, you have to take some efforts, no one will help you till end, others can just give you hints you should not expect all the help from others.